# Write a reusable logic in a socket data handler (Node.js)

Tags: javascript, node.js, sockets

I have multiple incoming socket data handlers.
And all of them share the same initial validation-check and a function that converts buffer into an array. Also, each time I need to iterate over the elements of that array and perform specific computation. However, it looks weird to copy-paste that validation and array generation code.

```js
// First handler
socket.on('data', (data) => {
  const tags = getTags(data);
  if (Array.isArray(tags)) {
    tags.forEach((tag) => { // Everything is the same until this point
      // Some computation
    });
  }
});

// ...
// Some other code
// ...

// Another handler
socket.on('data', (data) => {
  const tags = getTags(data);
  if (Array.isArray(tags)) {
    tags.forEach((tag) => { // Again the same code is duplicated up to this point
      // Some different computation here
    });
  }
});
```

How can I generalize this loop-based validation and array generation, and make an abstracted & reusable function out of it, so that I don't have to copy & paste?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Javascript allows you to pass functions as arguments. So just write a full named function:

```
function myHandler (callback) {
  return function (data) {
    const tags = getTags(data);
    if (Array.isArray(tags)) {
      tags.forEach(callback);
    }
  }
}
```

Now you can do this:

```
// First handler
socket.on('data', myHandler((tag) => {
    // do stuff
}));

// Another handler
socket.on('data', myHandler((tag) => {
    // do stuff
}));
```

The key here is the fact that `myHandler()` returns `function (data) ...` which is what `socket.on()` expects.

Answer (score 0):

you can write a function that run all of your callbacks in order

for example you have some functions that must run on every data

```
function isArray(data){
    return Array.isArray(data)
}
function foo(data){
// some computation
}
```

And then you have a function that run all of them in order

```
function runCallbacks(data,funcs){
   for(let i=0;i<funcs.length;i++){
      funcs[i](data)
   }
}
```

And then

```
socket.on('data', runCallbacks(data,[isArray,foo]));
```